# Newton Derivative Notation in LaTeX

Tags: support, mathjax

I personally like the [Newton notation of the derivative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Notation_for_differentiation#Newton.27s_notation), a single dot on top of function that is to be differentiated. So I was wondering if it's possible to use that notation in LaTeX?

Thanks

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use `\dot y` for $\dot y$, and `\ddot y` for $\ddot y$.

And even `\dddot y` and `\ddddot y` for $\dddot y$ and $\ddddot y$, but I hope you won't.

Comment: So I can use infinitely many d's before the dot?

Comment: No, there is no `\dddddot`.

Comment: so it's up to 4?

Comment: @SalmonKiller if you put infinitely many d's before the dot, it will work.

Comment: @quid: Infinitely many as the natural numbers, the negative integers, the entire set of integers, as $\Bbb Q$, some infinite ordinal (countable? uncountable?), some other linear order, some partial order? You should be more accurate in your description! :-)

Comment: @Asaf this is a physics notation after all.